# ctypes windll loading: interactive vs script

Tags: windows, dll, cygwin, ctypes

Running WinPython (64bit) on Cygwin, Windows (64bit):

From an interactive Python prompt (in the directory containing `myLib.dll`) I can do this:

```
>>>import ctypes
>>>lib = ctypes.windll.myLib
>>>lib.someFunc() # I can call the functions in myLib as expected
```

Of course, I want to load the library from within a script.  I have tried

`lib = ctypes.WinDLL('myLib')` and

`lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('myLib.dll')` and

`lib = ctypes.WinDll.LoadLibrary('myLib')`

all to no avail.  In fact, the error is

`WindowsError: [998] Invalid access to memory location`.

**How can I get the library to load from within the script?**

```
% myScript.py

lib = ctypes.windll.myLib
```

does not work.  Same [998] errror.

Comment: @eryksun, Right, so here is the mystery: I can load this library from interactive prompt, but any incantation from the script yields `lib = ctypes.WinDLL('C:/Users/tstephe3/Desktop/ranval_0/include/python/cellComplex_lib')
  File "C:\WinPython\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 998] Invalid access to memory location`, including your suggestion.

Comment: I can load this library from the interactive prompt using the methods you suggest. but `$python myScript.py` fails.  There's another error message in the output from that python call about "cygheap base mismatch" that I will try to nail down...

Comment: Good suggestion! Unfortunately both cases come back as being the same executable(`'C:\\WinPython\\python-2.7.6.amd64\\python.exe'`).  I'll have to edit this question because it's clearly not a ctypes issue.  Seems like some cygwin/winpython issue.

Comment: @eryksun: You've helped me out a lot here, and in the past.  I think this question is bunk - My calling structure was more complex than this, the library was being loaded in a module called from a script (not exactly what I let on in my question) - changing the order of import statements allowed me to load this .dll as you suggest (`ctypes.WinDLL('/<path>/myLib')`.  Another case of talking through it to get to the real issue - I guess I need a rubber duck.  Thank you.

Comment: Cool, I guess you can answer your own question. :)